# Node.js Setting Header complains can't set header after being sent, but it is before

Tags: node.js

In Node.js(Connect.js, actually)Trying to set the header but I get "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.". But I am setting it before the header is sent with `server.use(function(req, res, next) {})` so I don't clearly see what is wrong.

```
server.use(livereload({ port: lrport }));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, [
        ['Set-Cookie', 'mycookie1=value1']
        ]);
    console.log(req);
    next();
});

server.use(prism.middleware);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `setHeader()` instead. Not sure what would be the difference between `res.writeHead()` and `res.setHeader()` as far as setting headers is concerned.

Comment: `setHeader()` is just an in-memory edit of a header and its value in a temporary collection. While `writeHead()` send the `HEAD` of the response, with status code and any headers that have been set, to the client. And, once the client has the `HEAD`, it can't be modified.